# WPF-Accessing the textbox present in datagrid(xaml) in code using that particular datagrid events

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, wpfdatagrid

I have a textbox in a datagrid that is designed using xaml. Can I access the textbox which has been designed in xaml previously in codefile using the events of the datagrid. Please help me.....................

```
<Window x:Class="GridTextBox.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>

        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Name="datagrid1" SelectionChanged="datagrid1_SelectionChanged" LoadingRowDetails="DataGrid_LoadingRowDetails"  Height="auto" Width="auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="txtEmpid" Text="hiiiiii"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: can i access the textbox inside the datagrid using any of the events of the datagrid? --@BasiconWPF

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following Extension for the DataGrid.
Just create a new module and insert the following code.

```
Module Extensions
<Extension()>
  Public Function GetDataTemplateObjectFromSelectedRow(Of DataTemplateType As Visual)(ByVal lDataGrid As DataGrid, ByVal lColumnIndex As Integer) As DataTemplateType
    Dim lRow As DataGridRow
    Dim lCell As DataGridCell
    Dim lPresenter As DataGridCellsPresenter
    Dim lFoundObject As DataTemplateType = Nothing

    If lDataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
      lRow = lDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lDataGrid.SelectedIndex)
      lPresenter = GetVisualChild(Of DataGridCellsPresenter)(lRow)
      lCell = lPresenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lColumnIndex)
      lFoundObject = GetVisualChild(Of DataTemplateType)(lCell)
    End If
    Return lFoundObject
  End Function

  Public Function GetVisualChild(Of T As Visual)(parent As Visual) As T
    Dim child As T = Nothing
    Dim numVisuals As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
    For i As Integer = 0 To numVisuals - 1
      Dim v As Visual = DirectCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i), Visual)
      child = TryCast(v, T)
      If child Is Nothing Then
        child = GetVisualChild(Of T)(v)
      End If
      If child IsNot Nothing Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    Return child
  End Function

End Module
```

After that you can call the following Function in an event of your DataGrid:

```
  Private Sub DataGridButtons_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridButtons.CurrentCellChanged
    Dim lTextBox As TextBox = DataGridButtons.GetDataTemplateObjectFromSelectedRow(Of TextBox)(0)
  End Sub
```

The part `(Of TextBox)` describes your expected DataType and with the parameter `(0)` you describe the related `GridColumn`

Comment: Can anybody answer, why the above posted code does not format correctly? If i put in the contents of my answer in another posts edit window, it shows up correctly.

Comment: can I use it in the datagrid events ..... i.e. in the datagrid which is designed in xaml...for that particular datagrid event in code file?

Comment: I edited my post. You can just call that function inside an eventhandler in your codefile. I used the CurrentCellChanged Event, which do you use?

Comment: if it works as expected, you could mark this post as an answer, so that other people know, it is already solved and they find the solution in this post. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah for sure..just give me some time...will mark it as answered as soon as it works for me...

Comment: Can you suggest in other way...by using the datagrid name or either datatemplate or any other which is easier than this....Please help me Mr.bastionwpf

Comment: just copy the first block of code in a separate Module. Then use my example. What exactly do you mean with easier?

Comment: provided the solution for c# in a different answer. Please add related comments there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for C#

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
  public static class Extensions
  {

    public static DataTemplateType GetDataTemplateObjectFromSelectedRow<DataTemplateType>(DataGrid lDataGrid, int lColumnIndex) where DataTemplateType : Visual
    {
      DataGridRow lRow = default(DataGridRow);
      DataGridCell lCell = default(DataGridCell);
      DataGridCellsPresenter lPresenter = default(DataGridCellsPresenter);
      DataTemplateType lFoundObject = null;

      if (lDataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
      {

        lRow = (DataGridRow)lDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lDataGrid.SelectedIndex);
        lPresenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(lRow);
        lCell = (DataGridCell)lPresenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lColumnIndex);
        lFoundObject = GetVisualChild<DataTemplateType>(lCell);
      }
      return lFoundObject;
    }

    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
      T child = null;
      int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
      for (int i = 0; i <= numVisuals - 1; i++)
      {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
          child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
          break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
        }
      }
      return child;
    }

  }
}
```

Use the following call to get the TextBox:

```
private void DataGridButtons_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox lTextBox = Extensions.GetDataTemplateObjectFromSelectedRow<TextBox>(DataGridButtons, 0);
}
```

Comment: can I get the id of the textbox by using this? i.e. Can I use the textbox id in the grid event....suppose my textbox name is "txtClient" can i use it for any purpose like calling the methods..etc Example: txtClient.CallService() in datagrid event

Comment: whats the problem with the posted code? Just use the example in the second code block above. After that you can do your "lTextBox.CallService". The Object "lTextBox" is the one you want to have.

Comment: with the posted call you will always get the textbox that resides in column "0". Thats the second parameter in the function call. Just edit that to "1" to get the object that resides in column 2 of the grid.